# PhotoEditorSDK: PhotoEditRenderer equivalent on Android

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I'm finding the Android API documentation difficult to navigate compared to the iOS API documentation. The help section states to ask questions about the documentation on SO.

I have a pre-made JSON config file as a starter template so when users open the PESDK, there is already some text applied to their image. I'd also like to be able to autogenerate an image with the starter text on it using the pre-made JSON config file without the user having to open the PESDK.

The PhotoEditRenderer class in the iOS PhotoEditorSDK seems to do exactly what I need by feeding it a PhotoEditModel and an image object. Is there a class in the Android SDK that does the same thing? Is there any way I could achieve this on the Android side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately for the current version v5, there is no way to export layer like the Text or Sticker without the UI. Only Filter, Color Adjustments, and Focus are possible to render in the background.
There is an upcoming version v6, which is also split into feature modules.
In this version, there is an experimentally feature for background processing.

But this version is still in development and there is currently no final release date or prerelease date.

Best,
Sven